# Which options on Adobe Flash Player do I choose so that I could watch videos on YouTube?

Tags: 11.04, video, flash, youtube, adobe

Somehow YouTube wrote that I must have a Flash Player to watch videos, and apparently I don't? The website that was suggested on YouTube was:

http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/

And I didn't know which option to choose from. I thought that Ubuntu 9.04+ was
the right one, but I am not so sure. My Ubuntu is 11.04. Please help. Lauren.

Comment: you can just see videos in html5 by joing this trial (http://www.youtube.com/html5 )

Comment: not the question.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Flash is not installed in your system. You can please install it from Ubuntu Software Center, by searching for flash player and installing the Adobe Flash player.

I also have 11.04 and as because I had chosen to install the codecs during the setup process itself, flash is already installed in my system and working correctly.